# Edit colours in stacked barplot

Tags: r, graphics, colors

I have a stacked barplot based on a matrix, where columns by default form bars and rows form the segments of the bars. Now what I want to do is assign each cell in the matrix a specific color and/or pattern in the stacked barplot. That is, I do not want each row to have the same colour in the barplot. This is what seems to be asusmed by `barplot()`. Is this possible at all and how to do it?

Example (assigns by default color per row of the matrix):

```
barplot(matrix(c(1:12),ncol=3,nrow=4),col=c(1,2,3,4))
```

Example (my stupid intuitive solution that does not work):

```
barplot(matrix(c(1:12),ncol=3,nrow=4),col=matrix(c(1:12),ncol=3,nrow=4))
```

Comment: are you sure you want a barplot , not a matrix of color, where each cell (i,j) is coded by a different color?

Comment: pretty sure I want a bar plot. However the application is as follows. I want to built a set of 'missing data pattern bars' as known from the literature on missing data. See e.g. Figure 4 in (but my figure is much more complex) http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0376871604002339

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First I have adapted adata set so it is usable for ggplot, so it counts the number of times a certain value is present. Also note that it is important that the numbers change for each "Factor" (1 to 3, 4 to 6, 7 to 9) as otherwise it will not work:

```
Test1 <- sample(1:3,40,replace=T)
Test2 <- sample(4:6,60,replace=T)
Test3 <- sample(7:9,80,replace=T)
Test  <- cbind(c(Test1,Test2,Test3),c(rep("A",40),rep("B",60),rep("C",80)))
Test  <- as.data.frame(Test)
```

The next part is now fairly easy:

```
require(ggplot2)
Q <- ggplot(Test, aes(V2, fill=as.factor(V1))) + geom_bar()
Q
```

If you want the meddle with the colours you can use (spot the flags):

```
Q + scale_fill_manual(values=c("Blue", "White", "Red",
                               "Yellow","Red","Black",
                               "Darkgreen","White","Orange"))
```

I agree that it maybe does not seems so pretty, but I think is also fairly uncommon to plot something like this...

Comment: Thanks. How do I get from my matrix of frequencies to your syntax? Agree it's non standard. The reason is that the bars have a different meaning than usual (see comment above) -- Just like your 'flags' in the example.

Comment: >TestA <- c(rep(1,1),rep(2,2),rep(3,3),rep(4,4),rep(5,5),rep(6,6),
          rep(7,7),rep(8,8),rep(9,9),rep(10,10),rep(11,11),rep(12,12))
>TestA <- cbind(c(TestA),c(rep("A",10),rep("B",26),rep("C",42)))
>Test  <- as.data.frame(TestA)